# Control/filter to show/hide on Data Studio

Tags: sql, looker-studio

I'm trying to make a line chart on Data Studio but I'm going crazy.
I need to do a control/filter for METR_1, METR_2, METR_3, to hide/show them or just one of them.

| DIMEN | METR_1 | METR_2 | METR_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **DIMEN1** | Metr_1a | Metr_2a | Metr_3a |
| **DIMEN2** | Metr_1b | Metr_2b | Metr_3b |
| **DIMEN3** | Metr_1c | Metr_2c | Metr_3c |

In all my solutions, I have to replace the dimension but I need it.

Do you have any advice?

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves your problem (could you share a screenshot of your line chart?) but you might be looking for the [optional metric](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9484925?hl=en) feature. More instructions at the link, but you can enable this by flipping a switch in the 'Metrics' panel.

Your report users will be able to select any combination of metrics (`METR_1`, `METR_2`, `METR_3`) for display, from the chart header.